# Form doesn't get individual form ID

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an {{each}} statement which is suppose to have a form in. I can't figure out why the form doesn't use the forms unique _id. Any suggestions?

Path: `helper.js`

```
Template.Offer.helpers({
    jobOffers: function () {
        return JobOffers.find({candidateUserId: Meteor.userId()});
    }, 
    makeUniqueID: function () {
      return this._id;
    }
});
```

Path: `template.html`

```
{{#each jobOffers}}
    {{#autoForm collection="JobOffers" id="makeUniqueID" doc=this type="update"}}
        {{> afQuickField name='offer'}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit">Update</button>
    {{/autoForm}}   
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
id="makeUniqueId"
```

you make the form have id equal to exactly the string "makeUniqueId". To generate new IDs, omit quotes:

```
id=makeUniqueId
```

This will tell Spacebars to evaluate the function that stays behind the `makeUniqueId` helper, therefore supplying the `autoForm` template with proper value for `id` parameter.

Comment: Also, if you want to have `id` always equal to `this._id`, why not using `id=this._id`?